# Should I mention that I can't afford living costs in a scholarship application?

Tags: masters, application, funding, sweden

I am applying for a master's degree in supply chain management in Sweden and I can't afford the cost of living in Sweden.  I am filling out an online master's scholarship application form and I was asked to answer how I intend to fund my living cost. Should I mention my lack of resources in the application form?

Comment: If you are asked about it, isn’t it then obvious you should answer? Though why would you even want to apply if you know you cannot even afford living there? Are you implying that you suspect something like getting extra funding to cover living costs, or are you implying that you want to trick them into accepting you despite you not being able to make it?

Comment: This is likely an immigration requirement; you won't be allowed to travel to the country if you can't afford to live there. If you lie, you may either end up on a permanent "no entry" list or find yourself in Sweden and unable to afford living.

Comment: Is the scholarship enough to cover your expenses?